# VPN l2tp issue with VPN site to site : works on Debian, on 16.04, not on 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager

I did open this question a few weeks ago already :
[18.04 VPN l2tp issue - connects but no access to resources](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037380/18-04-vpn-l2tp-issue-connects-but-no-access-to-resources)

I'm still investigating but so far here are my findings :

- used to work with 16.04
- works on Debian stretch
- works on Debian testing
- works on Arch
- fails on Mint 18.04
- fails on Fedora 28

It is exactly this issue also :
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1802711#p1802711

Now, does anyone has the slightest idea how to see differences between Debian on which Ubuntu are based, and Ubuntu ? 
This is a very tricky network issue, maybe a net guru will step by ...

I've already updated xl2tpd to circumvent the 'kernel 4.15' issues. I've updated anything I could.
I've followed 'ip routing' magic trick : no better result.

What the hell can be broken in this distrib ...

regards.